# comparison with floats in neon intrinsics

Tags: android, c, arm, neon, intrinsics

I think this a silly problem but i tried for a day to resolve this with not luck, so here is.

i have register of four vectors (float32x4), and i want to make some process on some of them and the other i want to set it on 0's.

For example this problem in c:

```
for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    float b = 4/i;
    if(b<=3)
        result += process(b);
}
```

so the first one will not process but the other will, so i need a register where the firs lane i have 0's and the other one have the result.

But i don't know how to do this on neon intrinsics.

i know that there is a vcltq_f32 but i tried with this one and but with no result.

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this questions as **opencv**, but it don't seems to be even remotely connected to opencv.

Comment: sorry, you are right, i removed it

Comment: It's better to add a tag for **C**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
const float32x4_t vector_3 = vdupq_n_f32(3.0f);
uint32x4_t mask = vcleq_f32(vector_b, vector_3);
vector_b = (float32x4_t)vandq_u32((uint32x4_t)vector_b, mask);
```

Comment: thanks i resolve this with bitwise select but also this works for me.

Comment: yes; vbsl will also work.  vand has the virtue that you don't need to have a vector of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Neon but in most SIMD architectures you would do this by comparing and masking (bitwise AND). You use a compare instruction which then generates a mask which you can typically use for this.

Comment: A quick Google search seems to suggest that it *does* work, e.g. http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5229&view=next

Comment: ok I think i have de solution, with the bitwise select, this method recieve a mask and two parameters if the mask have 1's take the number corresponding of the first parameter and if 0 take the number corresponding of the second parameter, so with this i can use the mask the number that i want to apply the filter and another vector with full of 0's